# how to build polygon selector using `plotly` and `shiny`?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I know that there are already `box select` and `lasso select` to select points on plot panel in `plotly`package.

I adapted some codes from [this page](https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-plotly-events/) to select and print selected points using default `box select` or `lasso select`:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("brush")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs))) + 
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
  })

  output$brush <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click and drag events (i.e., select/lasso) appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I would like to build a more flexible polygon selector to select points and then print points, but I have no idea how to do it. Any advises and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd like to know whether this is possible with vanilla ggplot since I have noticed a massive performance drop in Plotly when you have more than 100,000 data points.